# pandoc does not recognize \mathscr

Tags: fonts, include, pandoc, markdown

I intend to use GNU `pandoc` to convert a markdown file, with LaTeX embedded, to pdf. But it seems not to allow `\mathscr`. 
Is it because `pandoc` needs `mathrsfs`, but seems not able to link it automatically.

Minimum example:
`test.md`:

```
Maclaurin expansion: $\sin x =x +\mathscr{O}(x^3)$
```

If being compiled with (on MacOs Sierra, Macbook Air)

```
pandoc -s -o test.pdf test.md
```

There is error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.59 Maclaurin expansion: \(\sin x =x +\mathscr
pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

Or, more generally, if it is due to the fact that `pandoc` cannot automatically find necessary packages, is there any way I may include LaTeX packages for `pandoc`?

Comment: no sir, it does not create intermediate `tex.` files. Thank you for quick reply; I need some time to digest what you mean.... I am new to all these stuff, Github and `markdown` and `pandoc`... ::><::

Comment: Why should it? `\mathscr` is only available if you load an additional package, specifically `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\mathscr` command requires `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`

It took a few seconds with Google to find [Lauritz' Blog](http://tech.lauritz.me/easy-latex-with-markdown-pandoc/) with an example that tells you how to add necessary packages.

```
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{mathrsfs}
---

# Section

Maclaurin expansion: $\sin x =x +\mathscr{O}(x^3)$
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!! it works!
p.s. this is my first question on SE :) So I cannot vote-up (yet)